# Platform that suits best to build a website similar to freelancer.com?

Tags: web-development

I want to build something similar with limited functionality. Just a basic version. Is there a platform that I can use like Wordpress for rapid development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freelancer.com looks like it was a custom built site.  I do not think a platform such as WordPress or Drupal will do you any good here.  Instead, I would recommend for you to use a framework such as [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) for you to build your site on (if PHP is your choice of language).  Of course, this requires programming experience, but I do not think it is realistic to build from a platform.

Comment: You say a basic version, so what aspects of Freelancer do you want to implement? The payment system, the messaging, or just the ability to post and read projects?

If you only want the project system, Drupal would handle this easily. You can use Views and CCK for this.

However, if you want all the messaging system, payment transfers, etc - you're going to spend so much time customising Drupal that you will probably find starting with a framework would save time further down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Drupal and the many many plugins available.  I think drupal may suit your needs better than wordpress will.
The curve for me is steeper on drupal than wordpress however.

freelancer looks completely custom built with its own api and the works. I could see any cms involved in its code.

You could learn ruby on rails or use django as your framework and have someone develop for you.